# DBPedia SPARQL query should return results but is empty

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to get all pages which have a specified category and a specified key. My query:

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://dublincore.org/2010/10/11/dcterms.rdf#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX grs: <http://www.georss.org/georss/point>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?page ?cat ?key ?value (lang(?value) as ?language) WHERE {

  ?page dcterms:subject ?cat .
  ?page ?key ?value .

  FILTER(
    regex(?cat, "category:Amusement_parks_in_the_Netherlands") &&
    ?key = foaf:depiction
  )

}
```

But it return zero results. See here: [SNORQL query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20dbpedia%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia2%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dcterms%3a%20%3Chttp://dublincore.org/2010/10/11/dcterms.rdf#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3a%20%3Chttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20geo%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20grs%3a%20%3Chttp://www.georss.org/georss/point%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20?page%20?cat%20?key%20?value%20%28lang%28?value%29%20as%20?language%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20?page%20dcterms%3asubject%20?cat%20.%0D%0A%20%20?page%20?key%20?value%20.%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%28%0D%0A%09regex%28?cat,%20%22category%3aAmusement_parks_in_the_Netherlands%22%29%20&&%0D%0A%09?key%20=%20foaf%3adepiction%0D%0A%20%20%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D)

It should at least return this page: http://dbpedia.org/page/Duinrell (because it matches the criteria).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a couple of things wrong with your query. First of all, don't use a regex when comparing URIs. Instead of:

```
regex(?cat, "category:Amusement_parks_in_the_Netherlands")
```

use:

```
?cat = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/category:Amusement_parks_in_the_Netherlands>
```

Second: your namespace prefix for dublin core seems wrong. You are querying the property `dcterms:subject`, and in your query, the prefix `dcterms` is mapped to the namespace `http://dublincore.org/2010/10/11/dcterms.rdf#`. However, the actual property in DBPedia is `http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject`, so your namespace prefix should map to `http://purl.org/dc/terms/` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Does the ?cat = ... expression also work when ?cat has multiple values? Each page can have more than one category.

Comment: @Alp, yes, the query pattern will match any page where at least one of the categories has that particular value.